# Why is MySQL converting field contents for half of my table?

Tags: mysql, date, set, double

I'm new with MySQL and am trying to load a csv into a table.  The csv has 50+ fields and everything loads correctly except the date field(about field #5 in the sequence). So I change the LOAD DATA to use the `STR_TO_DATE(@date,'%m/%d/%Y')`; and then the date loads perfectly.

However then field GG (comes about 10 fields after the date field)and all the remaining 20 fields in the table load as zero after the date field loads correctly.

What is field GG? Its a DOUBLE field that should receive a number like `999.9999999` into it.  In the source csv all the data for field GG is of the format `###.#######` except for a few entries which have the format `###.######.`

I don't understand why this is happening and where the problem lies.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Could you explain the requirement , also what's field GG. It would be best if you post a screenshot.

Comment: In the csv, the date field contains dates in the format mm/dd/YY.  The field GG is a measurement and all the numbers that will be loaded here are in the format ###.#######.  The date field is of datatype date and field GG is datatype DOUBLE.

Comment: I don't understand why all the fields load fine except the date field and when I fix it, all the fields at GG and after load as 0.

Comment: I think you need to format the CSV itself , plus could you expand the column of the date because that usually happens when it concatenated .

Comment: Please explain 'format the CSV itself' and 'expand the column of the date'.  Do you mean change the date field into 3 separate fields and load that way?

Comment: Just double click the column of the ###.#####

Comment: When I expand that column I see all the numbers to be loaded.  They are all like 654.1234567 except for a few entries that are like 654.123456.

Comment: Oh and there is one entry that is 654.1234.

Comment: Yeah, so you can format it via csv itself.

Comment: so everything is okay?

Comment: So you recommend changing the date to the right format then loading? I hope to automate this process but would I have to do that in SSIS?

Comment: Open it with notepad++ to check your results

Comment: For csv i'm unsure. but when you export what's your format you chose?

Comment: When I open the input file in notepad++ the date is in the format YYYY-mm-dd and field GG is actually much larger ###.#################.  But a datatype of DOUBLE should accommodate that format, right?

Comment: I didn't export the data to create the input file.  It was given to me.